# setuptools on python3.0

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I was trying to install "setuptool" package for python3.0. But unfortunately while 
I try to install it says module names "dist" is missing. 
   pls help me to resolve this issue.

---

#### EDIT AS OF MARCH 2013:

please look below the accepted answer for a more upto date response by @LennartRegebro

Comment: there should be a FAQ to tell people that "don't try a package on Python 3 if it does not explicitly describe itself as compatible to Python 3".

Comment: @Francis . you are right . I spend sometime before asking here to dig to the problem. which in turn proved to waste.

Comment: There is a Debian package for setuptools in Python 3. Install it with apt-get if on debian based system. The package name is `python3-setuptools`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Setuptools 0.7 and later supports Python 3.**

Setuptools was in practice unmaintained for a long time, and this prompted several people to join together and make a fork, called "Distribute", which was ported to Python 3 since 2009.

However in 2013 the projects merged, and Setuptools and Distribute are now the same thing. Installing Distribute will install an empty package that does nothing but install Setuptools.

Comment: From the `distribute` URL: "Distribute is a deprecated fork of the Setuptools project." Python packaging makes me sad.

Comment: @Christopher: Oh, you don't have to be, because the projects have merged and Setuptools is no longer unmaintained! I will update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can find them on the following two links: one for setuptools and another one for pip, enjoy!

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Answer (score 3):

**== This answer is outdated ==**

It seems that setuptools is currently in the process of being ported to Python 3.
Looks like there are some difficulties.
This is explained in more detail by Lennart Regebro here:

http://regebro.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/setuptools-on-python-3-work-on-hold/

http://www.mail-archive.com/distutils-sig@python.org/msg07183.html

http://regebro.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/setuptools-and-easy_install-for-python-3

Comment: @LennartRegebro: you edited this answer, do you still consider it out-of-date?

Comment: @Flimm: I edited  it so the links worked. But yes, it is obviously outdated and has been so since October 2009. It's not going to get any less outdated.