# Will setuptools work with python 3.2.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Will the setuptools for windows python 2.7 http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files be compatible with a python 3.2.x runtime. The installer fails to detect the python settings during an install. Should I wait for a new release?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816623/setuptools-on-python3-0 but this answer is better. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NOTE: Answer obsolete, Setuptools now works for Python 3. Distribute is deprecated.

Setuptools itself doesn't work on Python 3. But you can use Distribute, a fork and a drop in replacement for setuptools:

http://packages.python.org/distribute/

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

From the bottom of the page to install distribute:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py
```

Comment: Thanks very much, wasn't aware of Distribute

Comment: Good recommendation, it actually works more seamlessly than setup tools.

Comment: links are dead now